# XSL-FO format in static content depending on position

Tags: xml, xslt, format, apache-fop

I am currently transforming a .xml file with xslt into an xsl:fo file. The document shall be a presentation.
What I want is a sidebar on each page containing a list of all headlines (defined by a h1-tag).
I got this, but next, I want to highlight the latest headline on the current page, or any previous page, if the current page does not contain a headline.

I define the page-sequence as following:

```
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Presentation">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-start">
            <fo:block color="#fff">
                <xsl:call-template name="toc" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
```

Defining toc as following:

```
<xsl:template match="toc" name="toc">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:for-each select="//h1">
                    <fo:block font-size="18pt" font-weight="bold" margin-top="0.25cm">
                        <xsl:if test="is this h1-node the current headline?" >
                            <xsl:attribute name="color">red</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{generate-id(.)}">
                            <xsl:number format="1. " count="//h1" level="any"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </fo:basic-link>
                    </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried to use preciding-sibling::h1 but that does not work in static-content.
I also tried to solve it with fo:marker but the markers by the fop, so after the xsl transformation.
In other words, is there a way to make format a block in a static-content depending on the page or even the content of the page it is on?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to make the contents of the static content area dynamic? Is there anything in that question that raises a red flag for you?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to express the entire TOC in the static content retrieving markers, one marker for each entry of the TOC.  No conditional logic whatsoever, just retrieve all of the markers in the order you want positioned however you want.

Then, in your flow, begin by defining all markers as unhighlighted content.

Then, in your flow, when you get to each section being flowed, start the section and redefine that section's marker as highlighted content, then when you get to the end of the section, redefine that section's marker as unhighlighted content.

What you need to remember is that retrieving markers in static content is unconditional, while defining markers in flow is conditional.  You've incorrectly been trying to put conditional logic into your static content and that won't work for you.